# TfidfVectorizer in scikit-learn : ValueError: np.nan is an invalid document

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I'm using TfidfVectorizer from scikit-learn to do some feature extraction from text data. I have a CSV file with a Score (can be +1 or -1) and a Review (text). I pulled this data into a DataFrame so I can run the Vectorizer.

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

df = pd.read_csv("train_new.csv",
             names = ['Score', 'Review'], sep=',')

# x = df['Review'] == np.nan
#
# print x.to_csv(path='FindNaN.csv', sep=',', na_rep = 'string', index=True)
#
# print df.isnull().values.any()

v = TfidfVectorizer(decode_error='replace', encoding='utf-8')
x = v.fit_transform(df['Review'])
```

This is the traceback for the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/PycharmProjects/Review/src/feature_extraction.py", line 16, in <module>
x = v.fit_transform(df['Review'])
 File "/home/b/hw1/local/lib/python2.7/site-   packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 1305, in fit_transform
   X = super(TfidfVectorizer, self).fit_transform(raw_documents)
 File "/home/b/work/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 817, in fit_transform
self.fixed_vocabulary_)
 File "/home/b/work/local/lib/python2.7/site- packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 752, in _count_vocab
   for feature in analyze(doc):
 File "/home/b/work/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 238, in <lambda>
tokenize(preprocess(self.decode(doc))), stop_words)
 File "/home/b/work/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 118, in decode
 raise ValueError("np.nan is an invalid document, expected byte or "
 ValueError: np.nan is an invalid document, expected byte or unicode string.
```

I checked the CSV file and DataFrame for anything that's being read as NaN but I can't find anything. There are 18000 rows, none of which return `isnan` as True.

This is what `df['Review'].head()` looks like:

```
  0    This book is such a life saver.  It has been s...
  1    I bought this a few times for my older son and...
  2    This is great for basics, but I wish the space...
  3    This book is perfect!  I'm a first time new mo...
  4    During your postpartum stay at the hospital th...
  Name: Review, dtype: object
```

Comment: Could you display the head of `df['Review']` as it looks to me related to the encoding of the text inside your dataframe more than anything else?

Comment: Sure. I just edited my post.

Comment: And also `type(df['Review'].iloc[0])`?

Comment: `type(df['Review'].iloc[0])` gives me  `<type 'str'>`

Answer (score 156, accepted):

You need to convert the dtype `object` to `unicode` string as is clearly mentioned in the traceback.

```
x = v.fit_transform(df['Review'].values.astype('U'))  ## Even astype(str) would work
```

From the Doc page of TFIDF Vectorizer:

> fit_transform(raw_documents, y=None)
>
> Parameters:     raw_documents : iterable 
> an iterable which yields either *str*, *unicode* or *file objects*

Comment: This worked. Thank you so much. Marking it as the correct answer.

Comment: My memory usage explodes I use `astype('U')`, This seems to be a major issue when I use large CSVs. Any ideas why this happens and if there's a workaround?

Comment: "as is clearly mentioned in the traceback" is an unhelpful slight to the person asking the question

Comment: Couldn't agree with David more, this remediation is certainly not obvious from the traceback

Answer (score 26):

I find a more efficient way to solve this problem.

```
x = v.fit_transform(df['Review'].apply(lambda x: np.str_(x)))
```

Of course you can use `df['Review'].values.astype('U')` to convert the entire Series. But I found using this function will consume much more memory if the Series you want to convert is really big. (I test this with a Series with 800k rows of data, and doing this `astype('U')` will consume about 96GB of memory)

Instead, if you use the lambda expression to only convert the data in the Series from `str` to `numpy.str_`, which the result will also be accepted by the `fit_transform` function, this will be faster and will not increase the memory usage.

I'm not sure why this will work because in the Doc page of TFIDF Vectorizer:

> fit_transform(raw_documents, y=None)
>
> Parameters: raw_documents : iterable
>
> an iterable which yields either str, unicode or file objects

But actually this iterable must yields `np.str_` instead of `str`.

Comment: thank you so much for the solution. Would you kindly explain it a little more on the iterable bit between np.str_ and str? I'm green and confused, I thought str is iterable?

Answer (score 10):

I was getting MemoryError even after using `.values.astype('U')` for the reviews in my dataset.

So i tried `.astype('U').values` and it worked.

This is a answer from: [Python: how to avoid MemoryError when transform text data into Unicode using astype('U')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49957069/python-how-to-avoid-memoryerror-when-transform-text-data-into-unicode-using-ast)