# Python: how to avoid MemoryError when transform text data into Unicode using astype('U')

Tags: python, unicode, tfidfvectorizer

I am recently processing a quiet big dataset, and I intend to use Tfidfvectorizer to analyze it.

There were previous posts regarding MemoryError when implementing Tfidfvectorizer, **However**, in my case, the MemoryError occurs before I feed data into the Tfidfvectorizer. Here is my code.

1. read data

   ```
   data = pd.read_csv(...)

   data['description'] is the text content
   ```
2. process data

   ```
   from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

   description_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_features=500,
                                        min_df=0.2,                                    
                                        ngram_range=(2, 3),
                                        preprocessor=preprocessor,
                                        stop_words='english')

   description_vectorizer.fit(data.description.values.astype('U'))
   ```

Many posts here talked about MemoryError when fitting Tfidfvectorizer, but I found that when I transform the data into unicode, i.e. **IN THIS STEP**: **data.description.values.astype('U')**, the MemoryError occurs.

So, strategies regarding how to tune parameters in Tfidfvectorizer is **NOT** useful in my case.

Anyone encountered this before and know how to fix it? many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I know, this thread is quite old, but after encountering the same problem just now and not finding any answers I hope this will help someone finding him or herself in the same position.

The solution is quite simple actually, its just a small error in your code:
instead of applying `astype()` to a numpy array like so:

```
data.description.values.astype('U')
```

Just swap statements and apply `.astype()` to the pandas series:

```
data.description.astype('U').values
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In case someone wants to know, I found one way to do this 
[Python: use .loc to select data produces different results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49992273/python-use-loc-to-select-data-produces-different-results)

Maybe this is a dumb question, please let me know if you think I should remove it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced precisely this error as well.  The `astype` function returns so quickly and with so little additional memory actually allocated, I can only assume a preemptive calculation of a memory requirement is failing, its failing to find a contiguous memory block, or it's a bug.

I couldn't find much at all on how to **solve** this problem, so I **avoided** it by removing the `astype` conversion completely and converting the underlying data set to Unicode before it is loaded by pandas.