# Pandas DataFrame incompatible with sci-kit fit_transform() function

Tags: python, pandas, csv, scikit-learn

So I have created a classifier that distinguishes fraudulent messages from genuine messages. Snippet of the code is as follows:

```
# Import training set as DataFrame from CSV
dataset = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=',')
class_names = { 1: 'no-flag', 2: 'flag' }

# Separate training data to message, class pairs
X_train, y_train = dataset.iloc[:,0], dataset.iloc[:, 1]

messages = pd.read_csv('messages.csv', header=None)
X_predict = messages.iloc[:,0]

print "TRAIN:\n"
print type(X_train)
print "PREDICT:\n"
print type(X_predict)

# Vectorise text data
vect = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 2), lowercase=True, preprocessor=sanitise_message)
X_train_tfidf = vect.fit_transform(X_train)
X_predict_tfidf = vect.transform(X_predict)
```

I used to run this with ten-fold cross validation on the training set, using:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.1, random_state=1)
```

And that used to work fine. Now I want to use the entire training set as training data, and predict unclassified data. However, the call to `X_predict_tfidf = vect.transform(X_predict)` throws an error, as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "post-test.py", line 3, in <module>
classify()
File "/Users/user/Documents/MyTutor/mi_datawarehouse/classifier.py", line 90, in classify
X_predict_tfidf = vect.transform(X_predict)
File "/Users/user/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 1409, in transform
X = super(TfidfVectorizer, self).transform(raw_documents)
File "/Users/user/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 923, in transform
_, X = self._count_vocab(raw_documents, fixed_vocab=True)
File "/Users/user/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 792, in _count_vocab
for feature in analyze(doc):
File "/Users/user/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 266, in <lambda>
tokenize(preprocess(self.decode(doc))), stop_words)
File "/Users/user/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 119, in decode
raise ValueError("np.nan is an invalid document, expected byte or "
ValueError: np.nan is an invalid document, expected byte or unicode string.
```

What is interesting is that the types of both X_train and X_predict are identical:

```
TRAIN:
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
PREDICT:
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

What am I doing wrong? I've been going crazy over this as I've looked everywhere, including the `scikit-learn` docs.

NOTE: this is NOT a duplicate of [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39303912/tfidfvectorizer-in-scikit-learn-valueerror-np-nan-is-an-invalid-document), I have tried everything in that question and nothing worked. The data structures and problem are slightly different.

Comment: try ```X_tpredict.to_matrix()``` [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.as_matrix.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TfidfVectorizer in scikit-learn : ValueError: np.nan is an invalid document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39303912/tfidfvectorizer-in-scikit-learn-valueerror-np-nan-is-an-invalid-document)

Comment: @desertnaut I tried everything suggested in that other post, but nothing worked. Slightly different problem

Comment: @lwileczek you mean X_predict? That;s the one that throws the error

Comment: @CesarF ok, in such cases it is useful to indicate this explicitly in your question, to avoid being flagged as duplicate (I suggest you do it now)

Comment: You're certain X_predict doesn't contain any nans?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

quick fix might be to remove NaN. Try `messages.dropna()`

Comment: LEGEND! This fixed the problem INSTANTLY! Marking as correct answer.